# Filtered results are staying in their respective page not starting from page 1

Tags: java, angular

Current Result - I am getting result on different page after applying filter like 2 result in page 1 and 3 result on page 2 and 1 result on page 3 so on.

Expected result - All filtered result should come on page 1 as it can hold max 10 results and then if it increases it should go on page 2 and 3 so on.

```
public _onPageChange({ page, pageSizeOptions: { current } }: UxPageChangeEvent): void {
        if (this._pagingModel.currentPage === page && this._pagingModel.pageSizeOptions.current === current) {
            return;
        }

        this._pagingModel.currentPage = page;
        this._pagingModel.pageSizeOptions.current = current;

        this._isLoading = true;
        this._statusVisibleLoaders.clear();
        this._failureReasonVisibleLoaders.clear();
        this.loadTablePageData();
    }

    public _onStatusChange(event: UxValueChangeEvent<UxDropdownListItem>, id: string): void {
        this._statusVisibleLoaders.add(id);
        this.testRunService
            .updateRamTestRun(id, { testingStatus: event.newValue.value })
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
            .subscribe(() => {
                this._statusVisibleLoaders.delete(id);
                this.cdr.detectChanges();
            });
    }

    public _onFailureReasonChange(
        failureReason: RamRootCauseModel,
        contentModel: FailureReasonDropDownContentModel
    ): void {
        const testRunId = contentModel.testRunId;
        this._failureReasonVisibleLoaders.add(testRunId);
        this._failurePopoverVisible = false;
        this.testRunService
            .setTestRunsFailureReason([testRunId], failureReason)
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
            .subscribe(() => {
                contentModel.selectedItem = { id: failureReason.id, label: failureReason.caption };
                this.uxTable.update();
                this._failureReasonVisibleLoaders.delete(testRunId);
                this.cdr.detectChanges();
            });
    }

    public _onFailureReasonDropdownFocus(contentModel: FailureReasonDropDownContentModel): void {
        this._failurePopoverVisible = true;
        this._failureReasonChangingModel = contentModel;
        this._failureReasonChangingNode = {
            id: contentModel.selectedItem && contentModel.selectedItem.id,
            caption: contentModel.selectedItem && contentModel.selectedItem.label,
        };
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }

    public updateTestRunComments(
        { text, html }: RamTestCaseCommentContentEditedEvent,
        contentModel: TestCaseCommentContentModel
    ): void {
        this._commentVisibleLoaders.add(contentModel.testRunId);
        this.testRunService
            .updateTestRunsComments(
                {
                    text,
                    html,
                },
                [contentModel.testRunId]
            )
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
            .subscribe(
                () => {
                    contentModel.comment = html;
                    this._commentVisibleLoaders.delete(contentModel.testRunId);
                    this.cdr.detectChanges();
                },
                () => {
                    this._commentVisibleLoaders.delete(contentModel.testRunId);
                    this.cdr.detectChanges();
                    this.notificationService.push(
                        NotificationHelper.error(
                            'Unable to send comment. Please try again or contact your system administrator'
                        )
                    );
                }
            );
    }

    public _onFilterClick(event: UxTableFilterEvent): void {
        const columnName: RamAnalyzedSummaryTestCasesColumnName = event.column.value;
        const filterNewParentElement = AtpTableFilterHelper.getFilterElement(<HTMLElement>event.originalEvent.target);

        if (this._filterPopoverVisible && this._filterParentElement === filterNewParentElement) {
            this._filterParentElement = null;
            this._filterPopoverVisible = false;
            return;
        }

        this._selectedFilter = this._tableFilteringParams.get(columnName);
        this._selectedColumnName = columnName;

        this.lazyLoadItemsForFilter(columnName);

        this._filterParentElement = filterNewParentElement;
        this._filterPopoverVisible = true;
    }

    public _onFilterApplyOrClear(): void {
        this._pagingModel.currentPage = 1;
        // Update filtermodel
        this._tableFilteringParams.set(this._selectedColumnName, this._selectedFilter);
        this.loadTablePageData(true);
        this._filterPopoverVisible = false;
    }

    private initTableFilteringParams(): void {
        const filters: [RamAnalyzedSummaryTestCasesColumnName, FilterModelsType][] = [
            [
                RamAnalyzedSummaryTestCasesColumnName.TEST_CASE,
                {
                    type: FilterType.TEXT_FILTER,
                    applied: false,
                    caption: 'Filter by Name',
                    filterTypeHidden: true,
                    caseSensitiveHidden: true,
                },
            ],
            [
                RamAnalyzedSummaryTestCasesColumnName.LABEL,
                {
                    type: FilterType.REFERENCE_FILTER,
                    applied: false,
                    caption: 'Filter by Label',
                    label: 'Label',
                    existingItemsOnly: false,
                    multiple: true,
                    loading: true,
                },
            ],
            [
                RamAnalyzedSummaryTestCasesColumnName.STATUS,
                {
                    type: FilterType.CHECKBOX_FILTER,
                    applied: true,
                    caption: 'Filter by Status',
                    items: [
                        { id: RamTestingStatuses.PASSED, caption: RamTestingStatusesNames.PASSED },
                        { id: RamTestingStatuses.FAILED, caption: RamTestingStatusesNames.FAILED },
                        { id: RamTestingStatuses.WARNING, caption: RamTestingStatusesNames.WARNING },
                        { id: RamTestingStatuses.STOPPED, caption: RamTestingStatusesNames.STOPPED },
                        { id: RamTestingStatuses.SKIPPED, caption: RamTestingStatusesNames.SKIPPED },
                        { id: RamTestingStatuses.BLOCKED, caption: RamTestingStatusesNames.BLOCKED },
                        { id: RamTestingStatuses.UNKNOWN, caption: RamTestingStatusesNames.UNKNOWN },
                        { id: RamTestingStatuses.NOT_STARTED, caption: RamTestingStatusesNames.NOT_STARTED },
                    ],
                    value: [
                        { id: RamTestingStatuses.FAILED, caption: RamTestingStatusesNames.FAILED },
                        { id: RamTestingStatuses.WARNING, caption: RamTestingStatusesNames.WARNING },
                        { id: RamTestingStatuses.STOPPED, caption: RamTestingStatusesNames.STOPPED },
                        { id: RamTestingStatuses.SKIPPED, caption: RamTestingStatusesNames.SKIPPED },
                        { id: RamTestingStatuses.BLOCKED, caption: RamTestingStatusesNames.BLOCKED },
                        { id: RamTestingStatuses.UNKNOWN, caption: RamTestingStatusesNames.UNKNOWN },
                        { id: RamTestingStatuses.NOT_STARTED, caption: RamTestingStatusesNames.NOT_STARTED },
                    ],
                },
            ],
            [
                RamAnalyzedSummaryTestCasesColumnName.FAILURE_REASON,
                {
                    type: FilterType.REFERENCE_FILTER,
                    applied: false,
                    caption: 'Filter by Fail Reason',
                    label: 'Failure Reason',
                    multiple: true,
                    items: this.failureReasons.map(({ id, label }) => ({ id, caption: label })),
                },
            ],
        ];

        this._tableFilteringParams = new Map(filters);
    }

    private loadTablePageData(resetPage: boolean = true): void {
        const sortType = this.currentSortingType;
        const sortingColumnType = this.currentSortingColumn;
    
        if (resetPage) {
            this._pagingModel.currentPage = 1;
        }
    
        const {
            currentPage: page,
            pageSizeOptions: { current: size },
        } = this._pagingModel;
        const request: SearchTestRunsRequestFilters = this.getFiltersRequestModel();
    
        this.testRunService
            .getRamTestRunsFilteredPage(page, size, sortType, sortingColumnType, request)
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
            .subscribe(({ totalNumberOfEntities, testRuns: tablePageRows }) => {
                this._testCasesUrls = [];
                this._tableRowsTotalCount = totalNumberOfEntities;
                this._tableModel.body.rows = tablePageRows.map(tableRowData => {
                    return this.formTableRow(tableRowData);
                });
                this._tableModel = { ...this._tableModel };
                this._isLoading = false;
                this.updateFilterIcons();
                this.cdr.detectChanges();
                this.loaded.emit(this._tableRowsTotalCount);
            });
    }

    private formTableRow(ramTestRun: RamTestRunAnalyzedDataModel): UxTableRow {
        let jiraSystemUrl = this._jiraSystemUrl;
        if (this._jiraSystemUrl && this._jiraSystemUrl[this._jiraSystemUrl.length - 1] === '/') {
            jiraSystemUrl = this._jiraSystemUrl.slice(0, this._jiraSystemUrl.length - 1);
        }
        const editorLink = `/project/${ramTestRun.projectId}/plan/${ramTestRun.testPlanId}/case/${ramTestRun.testCaseId}/scenario/${ramTestRun.scenarioId}/editor`;
        this._testCasesUrls.push({ id: ramTestRun.testCaseId, link: editorLink, testRunId: ramTestRun.uuid });

        return {
            id: ramTestRun.uuid,
            columns: [
                {
                    type: 'checkbox',
                    value: false,
                },
                {
                    type: 'link',
                    value: ramTestRun.name,
                    url: editorLink,
                    unclickable: true,
                },
                {
                    type: 'content',
                    contentModel: {
                        tooltipData: ramTestRun.labels ? ramTestRun.labels.map(label => label.name).join(', ') : '',
                        columnContent: ramTestRun.labels ? `${ramTestRun.labels.length} Label(s)` : 'No Labels',
                    },
                    value: this.testRunLabels,
                    unclickable: true,
                },
                {
                    type: 'content',
                    contentModel: {
                        selectedItem: this.testRunsStatuses.find((listItem: UxDropdownListItem) => {
                            return listItem.value === ramTestRun.testingStatus;
                        }),
                        listItems: this.testRunsStatuses,
                        testRunId: ramTestRun.uuid,
                    },
                    value: this.testRunStatusesDropdown,
                    unclickable: true,
                },
                {
                    type: 'content',
                    contentModel: {
                        selectedItem: this.failureReasons.find(
                            failureReason => failureReason.id === ramTestRun.failureReasonId
                        ),
                        listItems: this.failureReasons,
                        testRunId: ramTestRun.uuid,
                    },
                    value: this.testRunFailureReasonDropdown,
                    unclickable: true,
                },
                {
                    type: 'link',
                    value: ramTestRun.jiraTicket,
                    url: jiraSystemUrl ? `${jiraSystemUrl}/browse/${ramTestRun.jiraTicket}` : '',
                    unclickable: true,
                },
                {
                    type: 'link',
                    value: ramTestRun.testRunJiraTicket,
                    url: jiraSystemUrl ? `${jiraSystemUrl}/browse/${ramTestRun.testRunJiraTicket}` : '',
                    unclickable: true,
                },
                {
                    type: 'content',
                    contentModel: {
                        comment: ramTestRun.comment ? ramTestRun.comment.html : '',
                        jiraSystemUrl: jiraSystemUrl,
                        testRunId: ramTestRun.uuid,
                    },
                    value: this.testCaseComment,
                    unclickable: true,
                },
            ],
        };
    }

    private getFiltersRequestModel(): SearchTestRunsRequestFilters {
        const request: SearchTestRunsRequestFilters = { executionRequestId: this.executionRequestId };

        Array.from(this._tableFilteringParams.entries())
            .filter(([, filter]) => filter.applied)
            .forEach(([columnName, filter]) => {
                switch (columnName) {
                    case RamAnalyzedSummaryTestCasesColumnName.TEST_CASE:
                        request.testCaseName = (<TextFilterModel>filter).value;
                        break;
                    case RamAnalyzedSummaryTestCasesColumnName.LABEL:
                        const selectedLabelsNames = (<ReferenceFilterModel>filter).values
                            .filter(({ customData }: { customData?: { existed: boolean } }) => customData?.existed)
                            .map(({ caption }: { caption: string }) => caption);

                        const searchTexts = (<ReferenceFilterModel>filter).values
                            .filter(({ customData }: { customData?: { existed: boolean } }) => !customData?.existed)
                            .map(({ caption }: { caption: string }) => caption);

                        if (selectedLabelsNames.length) {
                            request.labelNames = selectedLabelsNames;
                        }

                        if (searchTexts.length) {
                            request.labelNameContains = searchTexts;
                        }
                        break;
                    case RamAnalyzedSummaryTestCasesColumnName.STATUS:
                        request.inTestingStatuses = (<CheckboxFilterModel>filter).value.map(
                            ({ id }) => <RamTestingStatuses>id
                        );
                        break;
                    case RamAnalyzedSummaryTestCasesColumnName.FAILURE_REASON:
                        request.failureReasons = (<ReferenceFilterModel>filter).values.map(({ id }) => id);
                        break;
                }
            });

        return request;
    }

    private updateFilterIcons(): void {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            const filterElements = (<HTMLElement>this.uxTable.elementRef.nativeElement).querySelectorAll(
                '.ux-table__filter'
            );

            this._tableModel.header.rows[0].columns.forEach((column, i) => {
                if (
                    this._tableFilteringParams.get(column.value) &&
                    this._tableFilteringParams.get(column.value).applied
                ) {
                    filterElements[i - 1].classList.add('_filtered');
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question has way too much code. Can you [edit] your question and reduce it to a [mcve]? You'll have better chances that someone takes a look when they don't have to dig through all that code.